# Cannot read properties of undefined on page refresh

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, fetch-api, steam-web-api

I'm making API calls using async fetch. I've used if-else blocks to sanitize the input and give a response accordingly

```
if (username == '') {
        res.render("error");
}

if (/^([0-9]{17})$/.test(username)) {
        id = username;
} else {
        let user = await getUser(key, username);
        id = user.response.steamid;
}
```

Every time I start my node app it works fine the first time I submit an input but every consecutive time the app fails and gives me the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'steamid')
    at C:\Users\bursh\project\index.js:73:33
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Does the id get stored somewhere? This error happens when I give a blank input, reload the page and then give a acceptable input.

Comment: If `user.response` is sometimes undefined, then you should look at what `getUser` is doing.

Comment: the error itself says you have undefined the `steamid` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The render call after the if-else statement was being rendered regardless of the original error page render. I fixed this by putting the other render call inside the else to the `username==''` if